# How to query for properties with dashes in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to query for properties in Neo4j using the Cypher Query API. The query I am attempting is as follows:

```
String query = "start n=node(*) where (n.property-id = 'someid') return ID(n)"
```

I get an error when executing as follows:
Exception in thread "main" Unknown identifier `id`.

So, this means that Neo4j is treating the dash in property-id as a keyword. How does one go about formulating queries with dashes in a node/relationship property?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Escape the property with backticks:

```
String query = "start n=node(*) where (n.`property-id` = 'someid') return ID(n)"
```

Comment: To expand this answer, see the [Cypher language syntax reference](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-expressions.html)